# Given $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\mathbb{C}$ being $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent, find $B\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{B\omega_j}=a_j$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, entire-functions

I asked this question: [Holomorphic function such that $\theta\left(z+\omega_j\right)=a_j\theta\left(z\right)$ satisfies $\theta\left(z\right)=ae^{bz}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183695/holomorphic-function-such-that-theta-leftz-omega-j-right-a-j-theta-leftz-r)

That question got closed because it was a duplicate of: [Entire functions such that $f(z+\lambda_1)=af(z) \; , \; f(z+\lambda_2)=bf(z) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074745/entire-functions-such-that-fz-lambda-1-afz-fz-lambda-2-bfz)

But I cannot finish the solution using the hints given in that second question. Basically, we want to show the following:

> Given $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\mathbb{C}$ forming an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{C}$, and given $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$, prove that there exists $B\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{B\omega_1}=a_1$ and $e^{B\omega_2}=a_2$.

To prove this, write $B=x+iy$, $\omega_1=a+bi$, $\omega_2=c+di$. The equation $e^{B\omega_1}=a_1$ becomes $e^{\left(ax-by\right)+i\left(bx+ay\right)}=a_1$, which gives $ax-by=\ln\left(\left |a_1\right |\right)$.

Similarly, $cx-dy=\ln\left(\left |a_2\right |\right)$.

These two equations are linearly independent (because $\omega_1,\omega_2$ form an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{C}$), so they already determine $x$ and $y$, and I have no control on the argument of $e^{B\omega_j}$. So I do not understand how to find my $B$.

Maybe using that there is an entire function $\theta$ such that $\theta\left(z+\omega_j\right)=a_j\theta\left(z\right)$ for all $j\in\left\{1,2\right\}$ allows us to find a relation between $a_1$ and $a_2$ which helps us to find our desired $B$?

Comment: hint : $e^x$ can be thought of as turning rectangular coordinates into polar coordinates. Write $\omega_1, \omega_2$ in rectangular coordinares and $a_1, a_2$ in polar coordinates

Comment: I think that it is more or less the same as I did: my problem is that when we only consider the absolute values of $a_1$ and $a_2$, these values already determine my $B$. And it is not clear why this $B$ should satisfy what I want, because the arguments of $a_1$ and $a_2$ were not taken into account.

Comment: I had voted to close https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183695/42969 as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074745/42969 because I was convinced that the older question has correct answers. After double-checking it I am not convinced anymore (those answers need at least more justification). Therefore I have reopened your other question.