Proving that an entire function is exponential.
I was doing exercises of this document of ENS Paris (in french) and I am stuck at this one (the last one in the document):

Let $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z} \omega_1 + \mathbb{Z} \omega_2 \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a lattice. Suppose that  $\theta: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that there exist $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\theta(z + \omega_1) = a_1 \theta(z) \quad \text{and} \quad \theta(z + \omega_2) = a_2 \theta(z) \quad \text{for all} \quad z \in \mathbb{C}.
$$
Show that there exist $b, c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\theta(z) = b e^{cz}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

My attempt is trying to prove that $\theta$ satisfy the differential equation of $b e^{cz}$. We have: $$ θ′(z+\omega_i)=a_i θ′(z) $$  Therefore the logarithmic derivative of $\theta$ is $\Lambda$-periodic, hence constant and there exists a constant $c$ such that: $$ \theta'(z) = c \theta(z) $$
Which gives the desired answer.
Is my approach correct? 
Edit: I assumed that $\theta$ doesn't have zeros, if it does, say there exists $x$ such that $\theta(x)=0$ this implies that $\theta(x+ \Lambda) = 0$, then $\theta = 0$ by Liouville and $b=0$.

This works (space filler)

The logarithmic derivative is possibly meromorphic. Why should it be a constant? Note that there are also non-constant entire functions that vanish on a lattice.

Does this answer your question? – https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183695/42969

@MartinR Yes, thank you!

It is incorrect because in the case that $\theta$ has a zero, we can not conclude that $\theta\equiv0$. For example the Weierstrass sigma function defined as
\begin{align*}
\sigma(z)=z\prod_{(m,n)\neq(0,0)}\left( 1-\frac{z}{m\omega_1+n\omega_2} \right)\exp\left(\frac{z}{m\omega_1+n\omega_2}+\frac{z^2}{2(m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^2}\right)
\end{align*}
is a non-constant entire function with zeros at $\Lambda$. The case where at least one of $a_1,a_2$ equals $0$ is trivial. Assume $a_1,a_2\neq0$. Since $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are $\mathbb R$-independent, it can be seen that there exists a $c\in\mathbb C$ such that $e^{c\omega_1}=a_1$ and $e^{c\omega_2}=a_2$. Now consider the function $f(z)=\theta(z)e^{-cz}$. It satisfies the periodicity conditions $f(z+\omega_1)=f(z+\omega_2)=f(z)$ and thus is elliptic. However $f(z)$ is also entire since $\theta(z)$ is entire. By Liouville's theorem, $f(z)=b$ is a constant and therefore $\theta(z)=be^{cz}$.

This also seems to be an exercise from Apostol's Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series In Number Theory, Exercise 1.10.

Why does such a $c$ exist?

In fact, such a $c$ does not necessarily exist: for instance if $\omega_2$ is fixed and $a_1=\omega_1=1$, then $c$ only exists if $a_2$ is of the form $e^{2in \pi \omega_2}$ for some integer $n$. -1 until the issue is fixed.

This approach is wrong, see the comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1074756/42969

How is the problem correct if there might not even exist such $c$?

The problem is correct, but the existence of such a $c$ is not a-priory obvious. Just because $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$ it does not follow that the equation system $e^{c\omega_1}=a_1, e^{c\omega_2}=a_2$ has a solution (as pointed out in the comments that I linked to).
